# php filename encoding, ö is no real ö or what is "o ̈ "?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, readdir

i'm uploading images into a little cms on my php server, and now i have a file called "1372609671-Terrassenböden Watrawood.jpg" which causes some serious problems. i have downloaded everything to my mac and debugged everything down... facing that:

in my mysql table, everything seems fine, the "ö" appears as "ö" and i can find the file when i write a search-query with the exact filename:
[image]

But my php code fails, doing the same query. When i get the filename through the filesystem, with `readdir`, the resulting query seems strange:
[image]

as you can notice, the "ö" is no real "ö" anymore.. it is slightly bigger, but not as big as a big "Ö".. even the cursor is fun, i can stop in the middle of the character, when i hit then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the char, it first deletes the points over it, and on the second time the remaining "o"..

when i convert the filename using e.g. `rawurlencode` i got this:
[image]

you can see an "o" before the utf-8 stuff starts.. and then a %CC giving the dots and %88 giving a kind of space... what the hell is this? how can i get this down to a simple utf-8 "ö", cause using this stuff for a search-query will be useless.. :-/

For more details, the database schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `cms` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `upload`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `upload` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `file_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `session_id` varchar(45) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8965 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

everything is so far utf-8 on my cms:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Please show the definition of your table and especially the charset of the relevant column.

Comment: For some reason, `readdir()` seems to use the `U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS` character to display characters like ä and ö. This is weird because if ö (`U+00F6`) is not in a character set I would believe that `U+0308` wouldn't be either.

Comment: @Femaref just edited my question ;)

Comment: @Pietu1998 That depends on the underlying filesystem, not on `readdir`.

Comment: @Pietu1998 looks like a Mac. OSX normalizes all filenames to `NFD` before writing them to the filesystem.

Comment: @hobbs yes i can approve that, i'm working on a Macbook Air, with Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you have here. It's an o followed by U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS, which is a correct way to produce an ö. It's called a "decomposed form", while U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS is a "composed form". Decomposed forms are more general, while not every character has a composed form (they mostly exist for backwards compatibility). There's nothing not "real" about the decomposed form, and if it displays wrong in your editor it's only because your editor has poor Unicode support. When it comes to searching, again, any correctly-working search engine should treat `U+006F U+0308` exactly the same as `U+00F6`.

However, if you do need to work with broken stuff, what you want is Unicode Normalization, provided in PHP by the [normalizer](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) class. NFKC should give you the form you expect.

Comment: Sorry for my harsh reaction then in my question, i just never heard about that before :) But i will never stop learning, so i will give the Normalizer class a try

Comment: After installing LAMP on my macbook with macports (works great, did that because XAMPP won't work with intl after 2 hours of fails), i finally got php-intl running which includes the Normalizer class and this class solved my problem, i can now successfully generate the right sql to find my files with special chars again :)

Comment: @jebbie I bet you could have also changed the collation on your mysql column, but I don't know enough about that to say exactly how.